# Choosing a microcontroller for a wireless keyboard

Tags: microcontroller, usb, stm32, wireless

I've had my share of electronics projects and especially microcontrollers projects, having fun on STM32s lately, and I'm trying to pick a microcontroller for building a wireless keyboard but I'm a bit struggling to as I lack knowledge on wireless protocols.

My first concern is that the microcontroller supports natively a protocol that is viable for such an application, and therefore does not have an inherent high latency.

I'm pretty sure that this eliminates bluetooth, because I did try some BLE keyboards in the past and the latency was horrible, they would also hang on a regular basis.

- I first considered nRF, especially the [nRF52810](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/nRF52810?lang=en#infotabs) which according to nRF's website does apply for keyboard applications. Looking at the supported protocols I mainly see bluetooth, IOT targeted protocols and, less advertised, proprietary 2.4 GHz. I guess the latter is the most viable option (or not?). I did tinker with some nRF24L01 in the past, and I didn't keep good memories of the delay and information loss, but this a more recent product and [one of the proprietary protocolds](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/nrf/ug_esb.html#ug-esb) does feature "automatic retransmission of lost packets". It also does support multiple slaves (as the the nRF52810) which would be great for a split keyboard. Problem is there isn't a word on latency.
- STM32 does possess a wireless product line, but looking at the protocols I mainly see BLE and IOT protocols, and no mention of HID applications.
- From a little digging, it seems that TI eitheir offers proprietary protocol chips such as the CC2541 or the more recent CC2545 running on 8051 cores, which I can't say I love, or BLE only ICs with ARM cores.
- Looking at what's inside commercial wireless keyboards, I only found chinese no datasheet obscure brand ICs in the USB dongle, which doesn't help me much.

I guess what I'm really asking is: how do I know if a protocol is suited for this wireless keyboard application? Which microcontroller should I pick to be absolutely sure it will support this application?

Comment: Welcome!  Have you looked at plain bluetooth, as opposed to BLE?  Obviously it's actually designed for HID and keyboards in particular, so you'd have ready-made drivers in most computers.

Comment: Make sure you know the difference between "Bluetooth" and "BLE". The only things they have in common is the "Bluetooth" in the name and that they operate on 2.4GHz.

Comment: If you want something simple, you could also consider infrared, and you could obviously do this with any MCU.

Comment: You can't pick a microcontroller based on that only. If you don't use Bluetooth, you can't connect to a PC directly. You need one MCU for a USB HID to RF dongle, and one MCU to be the RF keyboard.

Comment: @jonathanjo I'm afraid that no can do for battery life reasons...

Comment: @brhans I indeed did not make the distinction between the two, but even if "legacy" bluetooth and ex-"Wibree" greatly differed in terms of history and implementation, BLE is (part of) bluetooth now since 4.0. But you're right I should stop saying "bluetooth keyboard" to prevent confusion.

Comment: @jonathanjo Yep, it allows to keep it simple but I can't allow my coffee mug to prevent me from typing text

Comment: @Justme Well I think that if for instance 2.4GHz "proprietary" protocols are the best for the application, then this elimates many choices and USB support or other criterion will do the rest. If BLE is fine, I guess price, USB support and my own taste for STM32 will allow for choosing.

Comment: @Mike656 Can I suggest you add your power requirements to the question?  Otherwise we're just guessing.  And any space requirements: ie, antenna distance etc.  NB re infrared: bounced off ceiling often works surprisingly well.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you say that you are proficient with microcontrollers but you don't know much about wireless protocols, my suggestion would be using a Nordic nRF52840 and the [ZMK](https://zmk.dev/) firmware. This would give you room to play with the FW but without the need of worrying about the wireless part of the project.

While on your message you specifically discard BLE, saying that

> [...]a protocol that is viable for such an application, and therefore does not have an inherent high latency.

> I'm pretty sure that this eliminates bluetooth, because I did try some BLE keyboards in the past and the latency was horrible, they would also hang on a regular basis.

I wouldn't agree with that (maybe you just had bad luck with the keyboards you used?). I would argue BLE is perfect for "most" scenarios.

If, for some reason you have a specific use case were BLE is not good enough, you might need to develop a solution like what most of the device manufacturers take: keyboard + usb dongle, using a proprietary protocol in the 2.4GHz band designed to have the lowest latency possible.

Comment: ZMK apparently [only supports BLE](https://zmk.dev/docs/faq#any-chance-for-24ghz-dongle-implementation) so why nRF52840 + ZMK and not STM32 + ZMK ? 

Thinking back on my experience with bluetooth keyboards I think my OS might have been the problem. I know that a 2.4 GHz proprietary means a dongle but what I am wondering is where can I find the metrics to be sure that for instance the nRF52840's proprietary 2.4 GHz isn't gonna suck ass compared to BLE. But I'm starting to think that this information doesn't exist, so maybe I should just ask nRF direcly...

Comment: Why not STM32? by all means! It just seemed like the nrf chip requires the last amount of effort.

Comment: About latencies, maybe you were hit by your device sleeping for too long, requiring a reconnection, where latencies are both considerable and random?

Comment: Sorry for the barrage of comments, I'm dumb. BT (or BLE) are not ideal (that's why they always add a dongle), but they are pretty good for this type of devices, so unless you have special requirements (i.e. gaming, or your eyes work faster than the average human) it's a good starting point. If you are happy with designing your own dongle too , check out also "Gazell", a proprietary link layer by Nordic that seems a good fit for this user case (can't link, search "gazell nordic")